# Javascript functional programming quiz

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Here is the problem. I have to implement **make** function:

```
var sum = function (a, b) { return a + b; }
var mult = function (a, b) { return a * b; }

//'make' function goes here

var res = make(1)(2)(3)(4);

console.log(res(sum));    //OUTPUT: 10
console.log(res(mult));   //OUTPUT: 24
```

I have implemented it, but I feel like a little better way still exists. :)

So, here is my solution:

```
function make(a, arr) {
    if (a instanceof Function) { return arr.reduce(a); }

    arr = arr || [];
    arr.push(a);

    return function (b) { return make(b, arr); };
}
```

Comment: The task is pertty bad. It forces you to inspect the argument and check whether it's a function or not. That's pretty un-functional in my opinion

Comment: @NiklasB. yes, at least once. At the end of recursion. But the task is the task)

Comment: I think the last edit you made is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: What is the output of `make(1)(sum)`? Consider `var comp = (f,g) => x => f(g(x));` and `var res = make(x => x *2)(x => x + 1)` then `res(comp)(3)`. The expected output is `8` but it is impossible with your sugary, sweet function. Attempting to implement this is a fool's errand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want functions? You can have functions!

```
function sum(a, b) { return a + b; }
function mult(a, b) { return a * b; }
function diff(a, b) { return a - b; }

function make(x, f) {
    if (typeof x === 'function') return f(x);
    return function(y) { 
        return make(y, function(a) { 
            return f ? a(f(a), x) : x; 
        });
    };
}

console.log(make(1)(2)(3)(4)(sum));   // -> 10
console.log(make(1)(2)(3)(4)(mult));  // -> 24
console.log(make(4)(3)(2)(1)(diff));  // -> -2
```

Instead of building up an array, this builds up a function that, when given a function, reduces all the elements using that function, from left to right :)

I'm pretty sure this wouldn't qualify as code that anyone would ever want to see in their codebase.

Comment: I wonder if testing `typeof x` is better than testing for a `call` property. No strong opinion, just a thought.

Comment: @kojiro: I don't know Javascript, I just copied OP's check. Feel free to edit

Comment: @NiklasB. I think, "arrays" solution is a little easier to understand. But I like your code. It is just great. Have you enjoyed the question? :)

Comment: I usually program in Haskell, so it was not too much of a challenge. In fact it reminded me of how horrible the Javascript syntax makes this kind of stuff look. JS has some nice functional features but just cruel syntax to express them.

Comment: IMO, single letter naming convention makes the code less readable.

Comment: @Pavlo Thanks for the feedback. I feel like `a` (as a parameter for `sum` etc.), `b`, and `f` are actually pretty standard notation in functional programming, but I agree about the inner `a`, `x` and `y`. Do you have any suggestions as to what they should be renamed to for better readability?

Answer (score 0):

```
function make(inp, arr) {
  if (typeof inp == 'function') {
    while(arr.length > 1)
      arr.push(inp(arr.pop(), arr.pop()));
    return arr[0];
  }

  if (!arr) arr = [];
  arr.push(inp);
  return function (inp1) {
    return make(inp1, arr);
  };
}
```

Comment: @NiklasB. I was in the process of making it smaller - when I noticed an update to the page. I just changed the part where the "inp" method was being evaluated. I posted the update to actually see the change and saw what he did and then posted a comment on his update.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better JavaScript specific solution:

```js
var test = make(1)(2)(3)(4);

alert(test(add)); // ((1 + 2) + 3) + 4 = 10
alert(test(mul)); // ((1 * 2) * 3) * 4 = 24
alert(test(sub)); // ((1 - 2) - 3) - 4 = -8

function make(x) {
    if (typeof x !== "function") return foldl([x]);
    throw new TypeError("Initial value can't be a function");
}

function foldl(array) {
    return function (fx) {
        return typeof fx !== "function" ?
            foldl(array.concat(fx)) :
            array.reduce(fx);
    };
}

function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
function mul(a, b) { return a * b; }
function sub(a, b) { return a - b; }
```

There are several advantages to this method:

1. Better error reporting when you write incorrect code like `make(add)`.
2. Simple functional definition which is easy to read and understand.
3. If you want `foldr` then just rename [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight).
4. Using [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead of [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to preserve original array.

I can't think of a better functional implementation for `make`.